# Why g++ pre-processor includes unused header files

Tags: c++, g++

I have created two header files and one cpp file like this.

**cat.h**

```
class Cat
{
};
```

**dog.h**

```
class Dog
{
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "cat.h"
#include "dog.h"

int main()
{
 Cat my_cat;
 return 0;
}
```

Then I have ran `g++ -E main.cpp >out.cpp` command and generate the pre-processed output. it was like this.

```
# 1 "main.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "main.cpp"
# 1 "cat.h" 1
class Cat
{
};
# 2 "main.cpp" 2
# 1 "dog.h" 1
class Dog
{
};
# 3 "main.cpp" 2

int main()
{
 Cat my_Cat;
 return 0;
}
```

After looking at this, couple of doubts came to my mind.

1. Why it included dog.h content even though it never used in the main.cpp file
2. In usual compilation, where does  create this pre-processed temp files (in memory or disk)
3. What is the sequence of per-processing and compiling (First per-proccess all files and then starts to compile or it completes one by one)
4. Does actual compiler uses `#` as the syntax for comments

Comment: Probably because it doesn't know whether it is used unless it tries to include them all and compile. You can have `Dog` class defined in one header, and `#define Animal Dog` in another, and `Animal a` in main.cpp, and unless it includes all headers and expands all macros, it wouldn't know all the dependencies.

Comment: You might want to read [this translation phase reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases).

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer from what I know:

1. Because the file was included with `#include` directive. That's it, no analysis is performed against what is really used. This analysis is normally done while SW refactoring by people or some other tools, not by pre-processor.
2. Depends on the compiler and it's options. For instance you can ask GCC to use pipe instead of creating intermediate files on the filesystem
3. Pre-processing, compilling, linking. The pre-processing is done in the order how the files are included. Means all included files together with the source file are joint to one large file until the end of the include tree. All that forms the translation unit which is later compiled by the compiller.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding number 4, that's not comments, that's another kind of directive called [*line control directives*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html) and tell the compiler what file and line the next piece of code comes from.

The compiler "proper" only sees [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (roughly a source file with all its included header files, much what you have created) so it doesn't actually knows anything about header files. The line directives are the compilers way of knowing if there's an error in a header file, and in which header file.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor just does text substitution on the source file.   So

```
#include "dog.h"
```

is simply replaced with the contents of `dog.h`.

It does not examine the content of the source file to determine if declarations in `dog.h` are being used.

The location of preprocessed (temporary) files is implementation dependent.   There may even be no such file - the preprocessed text might be simply piped directly from the preprocessor to another executable that does compilation.

The standard requires that the implementation (compiler and build chain) behave as if a number of phases are done in order.   One description is at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases.  However, a particular implementation is not required to actually perform those phases - it is only required to give results AS IF it has.

Generally speaking, the compiler (in the sense of being something that only takes preprocessed code as input, and implements Phase 7 at that link) is not required to treat `#` as a comment.   However, since it is invoked after preprocessing, an implementation is free to do so.   Note, however, that the preprocessor would interpret lines starting with a `#`, so would reject code that does so inappropriately (e.g. you trying to use `#` as a comment marker).

Answer (score 0):

The pre-processor is no a compiler. It does not understand C,C++ or any other language for that matter. All it does is process the preprocessor instructions (`#...`) and a few other tasks like concatenating string literals. It is certainly not in any position to remove dead code. Dead code removal is done by the compiler or linker.